# dynamic type in property of class

Tags: c#, generic-list

in the GetInfo method returned Result as JSON format like this:

```
"Result": {
    "Id": 11975,
    "Email": null,
    "CellPhone": "123456789",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Rock",
    "Avatar": null,
    "Address": null,
},
"StatusCode": 200,
"Message": "success",
"Version": "API V1.1"
```

i can deserialize result value to

```
public class SignInResultResponse
{

    public SignInResponse Result { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

}
public class SignInResponse
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CellPhone { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

in the GetList method result JSON :

```
"Result": [
    {
        "Id": 42022,
        "Title": "User Title",
        "Avatar": null,
        "Rate": 0,
        "RateCount": 0,
        "Status": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Title": "Active"
        }
    }
],
"StatusCode": 200,
"Message": "profile is not complete",
"Version": "API V1.1"
```

how to create dynamic Result property in Response class for any type of class ?

Comment: It seems you fotgot to view my answer below, try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

There is keyword **dynamic** and you can use it as type of your Result field. Though it looks like your two responses should be rather separate classes which might inherit from one **Result** class containing **StatusCode**, **Message**, **Version**. In your inheriting classes you will just add **Response** field of specific type to match response.

```
public abstract class Result
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class SignInResult : Result
{
    public SignInResponse Response { get; set; }
}

public class ListResult : Result
{
    public IList<ListResponse> Response { get; set; }
}
```

In such case you can see that Response field always exist but differs in type, so you might create Result class like:

```
public abstract class Result<T>
{
    public T Response { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

And then just use it when deserializing with proper type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Generic Class and JToken together to achieve your deserialized data from your response

```
public class StandardResponse<T>
{
    public JToken Result { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }

    public List<T> _Result
    {
        get
        {
            if (Result.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                List<T> signInResponses = new List<T>();
                signInResponses = Result.ToObject<List<T>>();
                return signInResponses;
            }
            else if (Result.Type == JTokenType.Object)
            {
                List<T> signInResponses = new List<T>();
                signInResponses.Add(Result.ToObject<T>());
                return signInResponses;
            }
            else
                return new List<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

In above class the property `Result` is of type `JToken` means any valid json can be deserialized into this type.

And then property `_Result` is of type `List<T>` where `T` is your any class that you want to deserialize your `Result` key data from json.

If your `Result` key contains data is of type

- Object then `_Result` will give you the List of a single object of type `T`.
- List then `_Result` will give you the List of multiple object of type `T`

So you no more need to check manually whether the key `Result` contains a data is of type object or array. The `_Result` property will do this for you.

**Usage:**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StandardResponse<SignInResponse>>(json);

var signInResponses = result._Result;
```

Now you are free to use any type of your class as `T` like I used `SignInResponse` in the above code.

Comment: It seems you fotgot to view my answer above, try it and let me know :)